# Destroy from column children does not remove it from children in qml

Tags: qt, qml

In qml, i'm having the following problem, i want to remove an element from a `column` component, and the element disappears visually if i call `columnId.children[index].destroy()` the problem is that it still appears in the `children` object.

By `column` i mean something like this

```
    Column {
        id: columnCData
        Item {}
        Item {}
        Item {}
        Item {}
        Item {}
        Item {}
    }
```

Note: this items are being added dinamically with a component{}

Lets suppose that in the qml javascript i call a function that will remove an item:

```
function removeItem(index) {
var _contentData = columnCData.children
_contentData[index].destroy()
}
```

It will remove the item visually, but will still appear on the children object and by that i mean this:

[image]

How can it be removed from there? Or do i need to do this in another way? using another property of something like that? It's very important for me to take away from there the items i invoked the `destroy()` funtion.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I _believe_ that `.destroy()` is only for [deleting dynamically-created objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#deleting-objects-dynamically). Haven't tested it out though.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, I'm going to edit the post as soon as I can. Thanks for the helpful answer, and yes this example was not the best, because in my real code I'm creating dinamically the contents of column. So the destroy() function is working well the problem is that children doesn't get updated as it should.